# ImportError: No module named Binary with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

[image]

I'm working through http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2015/05/13/python-oop-tdd-example-part1/#.Vw0NojFJJ9n .

When I try:

```
$ py.test
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.2.5, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: C:\envs\r3\binary, inifile:
plugins: capturelog-0.7
collected 0 items / 1 errors 

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_binary.py ____________________
tests\test_binary.py:3: in <module>
    import Binary
E   ImportError: No module named Binary
================= 1 pytest-warnings, 1 error in 0.20 seconds ==================
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add current directory to `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable.

As you are on Windows:

```
$ set PYTHONPATH="."
```

This shall help `py.test` to find and import the module.

Checking the `py.test` tutorial I see, that at "Writing the class" section they use exactly the same trick.

In practice, you do not have to do this, as you usually test against installed Python module (typically with `setup.py` in project root directory and using develop mode), and it is accessible for import easily without playing with `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Can you give me a reference to the "setup.py" you discuss?

Comment: The link is [In the tutorial you follow] (http://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/). There are many more pages to this (and it is not trivial matter). Personally, I use [pbr](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/). Assuming you work in git repository, it works very well and simplifies packaging to 3-lines long `setup.py` and nice to read `setup.cfg` in ini format.